# Bat file to run a sql query on a schedule through Task Scheduler

Tags: sql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a .sql script on a schedule. I have created a batch file to run the script. The script runs fine in sql server management studio and also when I run the batch file content through cmd.

Contents of the batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S omfmesql -U OMESRV -P orat -i "\\pvsrv-
fsr14\data\Projects\Stat_Table_Creation_unique.sql"
```

The sql script is supposed to update a stat table. When I run it though cmd and refresh the stat table, the numbers are updated. But when I run this batch file through Task Scheduler, the only action that seems to be performed is running C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe

The task is stated to be completed successfully but the sql query is just not run.

I am not too experienced with Task Scheduler. Any help here would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Note: I am not intending to use SQL Server Agent

Comment: I'm not sure that the Task Scheduler can pass your credentials through to the sql server.

Comment: system account may have not permissions to access shared network location. you may run task under some user account, known it has access to all resources needed. you are setting user and pass for sqlcmd can connect, but may task scheduler cannot access network share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not done so, you need to set the location in Task Scheduler (TS).  In at least some versions of TS, this can only be done when you create a basic task, not from the more general "Create Task..." option.  Ensure that all the paths in the batch file are absolute or are based in this location.

Comment: I specified the path of the batch file under the Actions tab in TS. In the General tab, I am unable to specify the "location". That is greyed out.

Comment: It's greyed out if you used the "Create Task..." option, but it should be editable if you use the "Create Basic Task" option.